# Deep learning model with less MACs and Parameters, but more inference time

Tags: deep-learning

I'm designing a lightweight deep learning that only has 0.8 million parameters and consists of several conv2d-bn-relu modules and dilated convolutions. Compared with a SOTA method (designed U-net) with 2.5 million parameters, I surprisingly found that the forward process of our model is slower, about 5%. FLOPs of our model is also twice as little as that of the SOTA model. Could anyone give me some suggestions on how to improve the speed of our model? Thanks a lot.

The environment is torch 2.1.0, windows 11, NVIDIA RTX 4090 GPU.

```
# our model
[INFO] Register count_normalization() for <class 'torch.nn.modules.batchnorm.BatchNorm2d'>.
[INFO] Register count_convNd() for <class 'torch.nn.modules.conv.Conv2d'>.
[INFO] Register zero_ops() for <class 'torch.nn.modules.activation.ReLU'>.
[INFO] Register count_avgpool() for <class 'torch.nn.modules.pooling.AvgPool2d'>.
Params:819.467K, MACs:410.132G, (input shape:torch.Size([10, 1, 256, 256]))
Average forward time: 0.0475 s

# SOTA model
[INFO] Register count_convNd() for <class 'torch.nn.modules.conv.Conv2d'>.
[INFO] Register count_upsample() for <class 'torch.nn.modules.upsampling.UpsamplingNearest2d'>.
Params:2.522M, MACs:455.281G, (input shape:torch.Size([10, 1, 256, 256]))
Average forward time: 0.0389 s
```

I have tried to fold BN into the convolution layer during inference, and it works. But the inference time is still longer than SOTA.